# regex expression to extract css comments with a shell script

Tags: css, regex, sed

I would like to extract css comments from style.css.

Comments are in the beginning of the css files and they are formatted like this

```
/*
Author:name
URI:link
etc
*/
```

After some searches I found :

```
sed -n '/^\/\*\$,/\*\/$/p' style.css
```

It didn't work, I had this error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `\'
```

Do you suggest a good solution.

If possible with a good link for a tutorial for basic sed uses for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed -n '/\/\*/,/\*\//{P;/\*\//q;D;}' style.css
```

Comment: Thanks,it works, but I just need the first bloc between `/*` and `*/`, your suggestion will show all the blocs. What should I add then ?

Comment: Your expression works,thanks. I am just trying to remove patterns `/*` and `*/` from the result, I was thinking that `-n` is enough but no, the patterns shows in the final result. I think I should add another sed to substitute them with blank.

Comment: I added `| sed '1d;$d'`

Comment: **`sed -n '/\/\*/,/\*\//{/\*\//q;/\/\*/!P;D;}' style.css`** would also work same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
sed -n '/^\/\*$/,/\*\/$/p' style.css
```

You had `$` and `/` in the first regep backwards.

Comment: Yes I think I forgot `/` , but executing this will show nothing.

Comment: It is weird that this `sed -n '/^\/\*\$/,/\*\/$/p' style.css` will not show anything

Comment: That's not the same as my answer, you have \ before `$`, which makes it a literal instead of matching the end of line.

Comment: Maybe your actual file has spaces after `/*` or `*/`.

Answer (score 0):

If they are always in a colon delimited format like that, you can use:-

```
sed -n '/Author/p' | cut -d':' -f2
```

That will get you the author name.  I'd definitely recommend learning about cut for colon delimited files.